# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Everything was working fine and I don't know what happened. I'm getting this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

I'm trying to get tags that are attached to post like this `@foreach($post->tags as $tag)` If I do `var_dump` then it says `string(0)""` if I do this with `@if(is_array($post->tags))` - no error and no tags. I don't know where the problem is because the categories are made in the same principle and they are working fine.

This is Post.php model code:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}

public function getTagListAttribute()
{
    return $this->tags->lists('id')->all();
}
```

This is Tag.php model code:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

Comment: `$post->tags` doesn't contain any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple call you can use for this case:

```
@forelse($users as $user)
 <li>{{ $user->name }}</li> 
@empty 
<p>No users</p> 
@endforelse
```

Please check the official documentation before you give inefficient answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This is a way easier. I suggest to use this solution instead of mine!

Answer (score 1):

If there are no tags then `$post->tags` is empty and therefor 
`@foreach($post->tags as $tag)` will throw an error.

You can check with `@if(!empty($post->tags)):` before the `foreach` if there are tags for this post or not to avoid a error message.

If there should be tags for this post but there aren't any then your `$post->tags` is not filled with data correctly.

Comment: But how this can happen ? The tables are all correct. Oh my god I don't saw that I have 'tags' field in posts table. I deleted it and now everything works!

Comment: Then please consider to use the answer @mimo posted (and mark it as solution), since it is a way cooler and better readable code than mine.

Answer (score 0):

when your array is empty, contains no element, **foreach** will throw that exception.
For safety you can use normal **for(....)** instead.